# simply stop an async method

Tags: c#, windows-phone, async-await

I have this method which plays a sound, when the user taps on the screen, & I want it to stop playing it when the user taps the screen again. But the problem is "DoSomething()" method doesn't stop, it keeps going till it finishes.

```
bool keepdoing = true;

private async void ScreenTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        keepdoing = !keepdoing;
        if (!playing) { DoSomething(); }
    }

private async void DoSomething() 
    {
        playing = true;
        for (int i = 0; keepdoing ; count++)
        {
            await doingsomething(text);
        }
        playing = false;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks :)

Comment: Try declaring `keepdoing` as `volatile bool keepdoing = true;` But if `doingsomething` takes too long to return, the user could press the screen twice thereby toggling `keepdoing` to false and back to true.

Comment: doingsomething doesn't take long, but due to the loop, Dosomething() takes time. & i'm sorry to say, but volatile didn't work.

Comment: Volatile is not the problem, because the code after await is always dispatched back to the UI thread... its not a synchronization problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is what a [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) is for.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts;

private async void ScreenTap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  if (cts == null)
  {
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
      await DoSomethingAsync(cts.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
    }
    finally
    {
      cts = null;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    cts.Cancel();
    cts = null;
  }
}

private async Task DoSomethingAsync(CancellationToken token) 
{
  playing = true;
  for (int i = 0; ; count++)
  {
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await doingsomethingAsync(text, token);
  }
  playing = false;
}
```

Comment: Should there be a `finally` block that sets `cts` to `null`? After the a complete (not cancelled) run, 2 taps will be required to run `DoSomethingAsync`.

Comment: @Gusdor: Good catch! I edited in a fix. It's not *great* - the CTS could be reused instead of just GCed, but it gets the general point across.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to use CancellationToken without throwing exceptions would be to declare/initialize CancellationTokenSource cts and pass cts.Token to DoSomething as in Stephen Cleary's answer above.

```
private async void DoSomething(CancellationToken token) 
{
    playing = true;
    for (int i = 0; keepdoing ; count++)
    {
        if(token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
         // Do whatever needs to be done when user cancels or set return value
         return;
        }
        await doingsomething(text);
    }
    playing = false;
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion because in my case it wouldn't be an exception.