# Cancel a library async method like Dns.GetHostEntryAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cancellation

Is it possible to cancel an async library method like `Dns.GetHostEntryAsync()` ?

I have hundreds of these tasks running in parallel (DNS blacklist lookups) and every now and then I need to cancel the entire list of tasks.

Example:

```
List<Task<IPHostEntry>> tasks = new List<Task<IPHostEntry>>();
foreach (string s in BlackLists)
{
    tasks.Add(Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(s));
}
```

Edit: This question is about library async methods which does **not** take a CancellationToken.

Comment: Tasks that support cancellation are usually using `CancellationToken`. I don't think you can cancel this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [simply stop an async method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614991/simply-stop-an-async-method)

Comment: Not a duplicate; OP is asking how to cancel `Dns.GetHostEntryAsync`, not the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is possible to cancel some async Library method, it is not possible for `Dns.GetHostEntryAsync` as you can't provide a CancellationToken to it.

For more information about how to cancel an async method that support cancellation, see [Cancellation in Managed Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx).

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
//Task.Delay allows me to provide a cancellation token
var task = Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0), cts.Token);
cts.Cancel();
try
{
  await task;
}
  catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
}
```

Comment: Ok. So the answer is "no"... That's sad because a Task could, in theory, run forever (not the Dns.GetHostEntryAsync thought).

Comment: @JeffMerlin It isn't actually all that sad - most of the time, the tasks that can't be cancelled wouldn't really be different if you would cancel them. The request has already been sent, you can't just send "Oops, nope, I changed my mind, don't send me the response after all.". True, there's some slight overhead for book-keeping of the pending asynchronous operation, but that's unlikely to be the truly problematic part.

Comment: @JeffMerlin And .NET doesn't really have any way of enforcing the abortion of any task; there is `Thread.Abort`, but that's more trouble than it's worth even if it *does* work in the first place (it only really works reliably in pure managed CPU-bound code), and writing abort-safe code is a *huge* pain, on top of the already huge pain of writing abort-less multi-threading. Operations that can be cancelled are the exception - be happy about those :) And even then, a lot of those (say, socket operations) are really just saying "don't bother sending me the data", rather than "abort, abort, abort"

Comment: Looks like [`GetHostEntryAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.dns.gethostentryasync?view=net-7.0) now accepts a `CancellationToken`.