# How to stop asynchronous method on form closing

Tags: c#, asynchronous, cancellation

I have a form which downloads currency rates and the method runs asynchronously. Now I need to stop the method when user closes the windows. I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614991/simply-stop-an-async-method/31652462#31652462) but failed to implement it in my code. Here is my complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading;

namespace ProjectPro
{
    public partial class GetRatesForPeriod : Form
    {
        public GetRatesForPeriod()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void closeBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        CancellationTokenSource cts;
        private async void runBut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

                this.runBut.Enabled = false;

                for (DateTime d = fromDatePicker.Value.Date; d <= toDatePicker.Value.Date; d = d.AddDays(1))
                {
                    if (d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || d.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                        continue;

                    switch(StaticValues.user.Language)
                    {
                        case "English":
                            this.statusLab.Text = "Updating rates: " + d.Date.ToShortDateString();
                            break;
                        case "Russian":
                            this.statusLab.Text = "Обновление курса валют: " + d.Date.ToShortDateString();
                            break;
                        case "Azeri":
                            this.statusLab.Text = "Məzənnələr yenilənir: " + d.Date.ToShortDateString();
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }



                    string url = "http://cbar.az/currencies/" + d.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".xml";

                    #region read rates for the date to the DataTable

                    var slowTask = Task<XmlDocument>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetXmlAsync(url, cts.Token));

                    await slowTask;

                    XmlDocument doc = slowTask.Result;

                    XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
                    XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//ValCurs/ValType");

                    DataTable tempRates = new DataTable();

                    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
                    {
                        if (node.Attributes["Type"].Value == "Xarici valyutalar")
                        {
                            //create temp table and load new rates
                            tempRates.Clear();
                            tempRates.Columns.Add("Code");
                            tempRates.Columns.Add("Nominal");
                            tempRates.Columns.Add("Name");
                            tempRates.Columns.Add("Value");

                            foreach (XmlNode currency in node.ChildNodes)
                            {
                                DataRow dr = tempRates.NewRow();
                                dr["Code"] = currency.Attributes["Code"].Value;

                                foreach (XmlNode currencyDetailsNode in currency.ChildNodes)
                                {
                                    dr[currencyDetailsNode.Name] = currencyDetailsNode.InnerText;
                                }

                                tempRates.Rows.Add(dr);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    #endregion

                    DAL dal = new DAL();
                    dal.ClearCurrentRates(d);

                    //insert new values
                    foreach (DataRow currencyRow in StaticValues.dataSet.Tables["Currencies"].Rows)
                    {
                        if (currencyRow["Code"].ToString() == "AZN")
                        {
                            #region Insert the row for AZN
                            try
                            {
                                SqlParameter[] pars = new SqlParameter[3];

                                pars[0] = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Date);
                                pars[0].Value = d.ToShortDateString();

                                pars[1] = new SqlParameter("@currencyCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                                pars[1].Value = currencyRow[1].ToString();

                                pars[2] = new SqlParameter("@Rate", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                                pars[2].Value = 1;

                                dal.InsertData("CurrencyRates", pars);
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                StaticValues.WriteEventLogXML(ex, this.Text);
                                switch (StaticValues.user.Language)
                                {
                                    case "English":
                                        MessageBox.Show("Database error", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                        break;
                                    case "Russian":
                                        MessageBox.Show("Ошибка базы данных", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                        break;
                                    case "Azeri":
                                        MessageBox.Show("Məlumat bazası səhvi", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            #endregion
                            continue;
                        }
                        foreach (DataRow tempRow in tempRates.Rows)
                        {
                            if (tempRow["Code"].ToString() == currencyRow["Code"].ToString())
                            {
                                #region Insert the row
                                try
                                {
                                    SqlParameter[] pars = new SqlParameter[3];

                                    pars[0] = new SqlParameter("@Date", SqlDbType.Date);
                                    pars[0].Value = d.ToShortDateString();

                                    pars[1] = new SqlParameter("@currencyCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
                                    pars[1].Value = currencyRow[1].ToString();

                                    pars[2] = new SqlParameter("@Rate", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                                    pars[2].Value = decimal.Parse(tempRow["Value"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                                    dal.InsertData("CurrencyRates", pars);
                                    break;
                                }
                                catch (Exception ex)
                                {
                                    StaticValues.WriteEventLogXML(ex, this.Text);
                                    switch (StaticValues.user.Language)
                                    {
                                        case "English":
                                            MessageBox.Show("Database error", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                            break;
                                        case "Russian":
                                            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка базы данных", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                            break;
                                        case "Azeri":
                                            MessageBox.Show("Məlumat bazası səhvi", Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                                            break;
                                        default:
                                            break;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                                #endregion
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
            {
                StaticValues.WriteEventLogXML(ex, this.Text);
                switch (StaticValues.user.Language)
                {
                    case "English":
                        this.statusLab.Text = "Cancelled";
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    case "Russian":
                        this.statusLab.Text = "Готово";
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    case "Azeri":
                        this.statusLab.Text = "Dayandırılıb.";
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StaticValues.WriteEventLogXML(ex, this.Text);
                switch (StaticValues.user.Language)
                {
                    case "English":
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    case "Russian":
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    case "Azeri":
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                switch (StaticValues.user.Language)
                {
                    case "English":
                        this.statusLab.Text = "Ready";
                        break;
                    case "Russian":
                        this.statusLab.Text = "Готово";
                        break;
                    case "Azeri":
                        this.statusLab.Text = "Hazır";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                this.runBut.Enabled = true;
            }            
        }


        private XmlDocument GetXmlAsync(string url, CancellationToken tok)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(url);

            return doc;
        }

        private void GetRatesForPeriod_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cts != null)
                cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put breakpoint on cts.Cancel(); line and make sure it is heating that or not,  and you can subscribe to the Form.Closing event

Comment: it's quite a bit of code but the only place I could see you using `cts.Token` is in the inner tasks - you should add some code to break out of your loop when you cancel too! Also why the `Thread.Sleep` - you will get at least a couple of seconds wait time this way

Comment: @Jamaxack, I have put a breakpoint there and it hits. I have also added Form.Closing, thank you for the note.

Comment: @Carsten, I need Thread.Sleep because otherwise the server returns an error for some reason (maybe security).

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in here:

```
    private XmlDocument GetXmlAsync(string url, CancellationToken tok)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(url);

        return doc;
    }
```

The XmlDocument is not asynchronous, nor do you use the cancellation token at all. You would have to modify this method to load the URL asynchronously. One candidate might be to use `HttpClient`. I found an example here which might be helpful.

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me with that. I have no experience with this unfortunately... It loads the rates well and the windows is responsive and does not freeze so I guess async method itself runs well. But when I close the form the rates keep updating.